# Replace - to : in the dict.values to use it for delete slices in dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

i need to replace **-** to **:** in a dict. The reason is that i need this to delete automatically slices from a dataframe. I got this from a csv so i cant change the inputs.

My dict is looking like this

```
alpha = {'a':'12-15,20-25','b':'10-15,100-250'}
```

At the end i want a dict where i can get the name a and pick the slice for example 12:15 to delete this rows in a dataframe called a

Comment: So what did you try?

Comment: i want to get a= 12:15,20:25 so i can use it to remove slices from dataframe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
        for key in alpha:
            alpha[key] = alpha[key].replace('-', ':')
```

Comment: nice this is working. do you know i can get the parts. for example 12:15

Comment: @credenco you can do `alpha[key].split(',')` in the loop to get a list of the parts ie `['12:15', '20:25']`